# How to upload a file after the onchange event of file input

Tags: php, ajax

I want to upload an image via AJAX once the file input changes, but I don't know where I am going wrong. It's easier to send text than files.

```
<input type="file" name="photovideo" id="photovideo">
```

```
$(document).on("change","#photovideo",function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'alert_users/main/potovideo.php',
    data:new FormData(this),
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    cache:false,
    success: function(message){
      alert(message);
    },
    error:function(){
      alert("error");
    }
  });
  //...
});
```

I just want to return the name to make sure the request is processed:

```
 echo $name = $_FILES['photovideo']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used this to submit files

```
<form id="yourImages" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<script>
    $("body").on('change', '#file', function() {
        $( "#yourImages" ).ajaxForm({}).submit();
    });
</script>
```

But you need AjaxForm for it...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's a lot simpler to use `.submit()` or `.trigger('submit')` rather than including an additional library

Comment: @Spencer might be but our site has some more use then that for the library. :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to create `FormData` with an input, while you should do it with a form. So change this line:

```
data:new FormData(this),
```

To this:

```
data:new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]), // Get the parent form
```